# Java MySql PoolableConnectionFactory &

Tags: java, mysql, database-connection

I have a working code, which works fine on two other machines. those machines have local mysql server instances running on them.

Now procured a new machine and installed Mysql server on this and am trying to run the same code, which works fine in other machines. But getting the poolable connection factory error. pasting the whole error for your reference.

ensured that max_connections is over 1K and have set appropriate variables correctly. But still not able to connect to DB. 
Used latest MySql connector, however still facing the issue.

Am able to connect to Sql from the terminal and from workbench, however, the problem occurs only when trying to connect to MySQL from eclipse using java.

I vaguely remember me facing the same issue on other machines, when mysql was freshly installed, however, I couldn't remember the solution. The issue was with some mysql Variable, which was causing the issue.

Could someone help me out on how this problem could be resolved? which variables need to be changed.

```
java.sql.SQLException: Cannot create PoolableConnectionFactory (Could not create connection to database server. Attempted reconnect 3 times. Giving up.)
    at org.apache.commons.dbcp2.BasicDataSource.createPoolableConnectionFactory(BasicDataSource.java:2291)
    at org.apache.commons.dbcp2.BasicDataSource.createDataSource(BasicDataSource.java:2038)
    at org.apache.commons.dbcp2.BasicDataSource.getConnection(BasicDataSource.java:1533)
    at com.Common.Handles.Td_Mmm_Data.getConnection(Td_Mmm_Data.java:71)
    at com.TD.TableOperations.asdf.asdfghj(TBLO_ORDERS.java:141)
    at poe.P4_DBDataAnalyzers.Engines.asdfghjk.getAllCsRecos(UpdateAllcs.java:230)
    at poe.P4_DBDataAnalyzers.Engines.asdfghjk.UpdateCsRecos(UpdateAllcs.java:52)
    at Alpha.EnginesManager.asdfghjk(EnginesManager.java:132)
    at Alpha.PreOpenEngines.main(PreOpenEngines.java:19)
Caused by: com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLNonTransientConnectionException: Could not create connection to database server. Attempted reconnect 3 times. Giving up.
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.handleNewInstance(Util.java:404)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.getInstance(Util.java:387)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:917)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:896)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:885)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:860)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.connectWithRetries(ConnectionImpl.java:2165)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.createNewIO(ConnectionImpl.java:2090)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.<init>(ConnectionImpl.java:795)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.JDBC4Connection.<init>(JDBC4Connection.java:44)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.handleNewInstance(Util.java:404)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.getInstance(ConnectionImpl.java:400)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.NonRegisteringDriver.connect(NonRegisteringDriver.java:327)
    at org.apache.commons.dbcp2.DriverConnectionFactory.createConnection(DriverConnectionFactory.java:39)
    at org.apache.commons.dbcp2.PoolableConnectionFactory.makeObject(PoolableConnectionFactory.java:256)
    at org.apache.commons.dbcp2.BasicDataSource.validateConnectionFactory(BasicDataSource.java:2301)
    at org.apache.commons.dbcp2.BasicDataSource.createPoolableConnectionFactory(BasicDataSource.java:2287)
    ... 8 more
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.getServerCharset(ConnectionImpl.java:3005)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sendConnectionAttributes(MysqlIO.java:1916)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.proceedHandshakeWithPluggableAuthentication(MysqlIO.java:1845)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.doHandshake(MysqlIO.java:1215)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.coreConnect(ConnectionImpl.java:2255)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.connectWithRetries(ConnectionImpl.java:2106)
    ... 22 more
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.Common.Handles.Td_Mmm_Data.closeConnection(Td_Mmm_Data.java:96)
    at com.TD.TableOperations.qwerqwer.GetAllEntriesAsList(TBLO_ORDERS.java:150)
    at poe.P4_DBDataAnalyzers.Engines.qwerqwerqwerweqr.getAllCsRecos(UpdateAllcsRecosManager.java:230)
    at poe.P4_DBDataAnalyzers.Engines.qwerqewrqewwqerqwerqwer.Updatecs(UpdateAllCs.java:52)
    at Alpha.EnginesManager.qwerweqqwerqwer(EnginesManager.java:132)
    at Alpha.PreOpenEngines.main(PreOpenEngines.java:19)
```

Comment: Are you able to make connection via a command line client? If yes, check what this line is doing `com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.getServerCharset(ConnectionImpl.java:3005)` maybe a hint to the underlying problem.

Comment: Able to connect from terminal. I think char set is ccr32 by default. Nothing is changed.

Comment: I assume you are using the same version of mysql server as it is on other machines. And the driver jar being used is also same. And make sure both these are compatible with each other.

Comment: Version is different. However, tried using the ini file from the other machine. But the problem persists.

Comment: Then first check would be checking if mysql connector jar is compatible with this version of mysql server. You will possibly find a catch there. Also let know the server version and connector jar version, on machine that is not working

Comment: Installed mysql this week. Version 8.0.15. Tried with Connector 8.0.11 and 16.

Comment: This is compatible - https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-j/8.0/en/connector-j-versions.html. Falling back to original statement something failed around this line `com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.getServerCharset(ConnectionImpl.java:3005)`, check what is happening and fix the server config. I don't have decompiler with me to check the code :(.

Answer (score 0):

Worked through line by line and checked everything. Solved the problem Finally.

1. Multiple projects were added to the project. There were some references to old MySql connector.
2. Some changes in MySql 8.0 and above and needed the flag "&allowPublicKeyRetrieval=true" which was causing connectivity issues.
3. In addition, Max_Connections in mysql variables needed to be changed. Connection Time out settings needed to be tweaked. 
   Thank you all for your inputs.